# Difference between explaining and explanatory?

Tags: meaning, differences, nuance

What's the difference between something being *explaining* and being *explanatory*?

I've looked in the dictionary and the translations to my language are the same. Yet both forms can be seen in common text.
Are they synonyms?

Comment: Translations? Do you mean "definitions"?

Comment: As Souta says, they have almost the same meaning, but are grammatically completely different, and I can't think of a context in which they are interchangeable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to **explain** my answer, even though I find the dictionary to be **explanatory**.

You often *explain* something.
However, when you go to choose 'best answer', you're going to find their answer *explanatory*.

explain ([dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/explain?q=explain)):

> verb: 
>   make (an idea or situation) clear to someone by describing it in more detail or revealing relevant facts

explanatory ([dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/explanatory)):

> adjective:
>   serving to explain something

So, *explain* is something you do, whereas *explanatory* describes what *is*.

Further example:

I am going to *explain* this answer one last time.

I write this answer *explaining* what the difference is.

After writing this, I find this to be an *explanatory* answer.

Comment: Ok, so a description would be rather explanatory than explaining, right?

Comment: @OndraŽižka As long as your describing the description as explanatory, yes. Explaining is a verb. Explanatory is an adjective, meant to describe something.